# asp.net mvc get values from multiple dropdown

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Below is my code where the i get data from 2 viewbags. one viewbag has the property lists and the other one is a dropdown. how do i get the property list and its corresponding value in the javascipt.

asp.mvc razor view code:

```
@if (ViewBag.ddlcolmapping != null && ViewBag.excelheaders != null)
{
    foreach (var proplists in ViewBag.ddlcolmapping)
    {
        <div>
            <a data-id='@proplists' id='ColumnSelect_@(proplists)' href="#" class="select-categories">@proplists</a>
            @Html.DropDownList("ddl", new SelectList(ViewBag.excelheaders), new { @id = @proplists })
            <br/><br/>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Javascript code

```
function SaveMapping(elem) {
        debugger;
       ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please define what `ddlcolmapping ` and `excelheaders ` are? What are the underlying classes? By JavaScript do you mean HTML?

Comment: Both are List<string> and contains strings. By javascript i mean in SaveMapping function how can i map the list value to the selected value in dropdown.

Comment: One is displayed as a string, the other is a dropdown and i just want to map the string with the selected value in dropdown

Comment: I think the best way would be to create a `SelectList` in your controller or use `razor` to build you links and select list. What are you using the property list for?

Comment: All I want is one displayed as string and then the other displayed as dropdown and when i click on save some type of mapping should happen so that the string and the selected value from dropdown are mapped and saved in the text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can offer a solution using JQuery. I'd give some class name to the outer div something like

```
<div class="someDiv">
            <a data-id='@proplists' id='ColumnSelect_@(proplists)' href="#" class="select-categories">@proplists</a>
            @Html.DropDownList("ddl", new SelectList(ViewBag.excelheaders), new { @id = @proplists })
            <br/><br/>
        </div>
```

And then in the javascript using JQuery, you can do call the following code on some click or any event that you are using to capture the anchor tag text and the selected value from the dropdown. I have thrown some alert to show you how you can pull the value.

```
$("div.someDiv").each(function () {
            alert($(this).find('a').text());
            alert($(this).find('select>option:selected').text());
        })
```